# Use System.Text.Json source generator with custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json, .net-6.0, sourcegenerators

How are custom `JsonConverter<>` classes used together with `System.Text.Json` source generator?

I would like to call `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType[]>()` that doesn't fallback to a reflection-based implementation and uses a custom `MyTypeJsonParser : JsonConverter<MyType>`.

EDIT to clarify: Custom converter is implemented for `MyType`, but json contains an array of `MyType` objects. So, I would like to create source generated `JsonSerializerContext` that deserializes an `array` of `MyType` objects (`MyType[]`), using generated code to deserialize an `array` part and manual converter to deserialize a `MyType` objects part.

Old code *(that doesn't use a source generator)* applies a custom converter, by adding it to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`.

However, upon further research I found out that `Converters` property is missing in `JsonSourceGenerationOptionsAttribute`. The tables in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-source-generation-modes?pivots=dotnet-6-0) also state that `JsonConverterAttribute` and `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters` are **not** supported in *serialization optimization mode*. So, it seems that mixing of custom converters with json source generator is currently (.NET 6) not possible.

The documentation is not clear, whether at least *metadata collection* source generation mode can use `JsonConverterAttribute`.

Comment: Could you clarify a little?  How are you applying the converter?  1) Via `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyTypeJsonParser))]` on a property?  2) `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyTypeJsonParser))]` on `MyType` itself?  3) By adding it to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`?  Also, converters are used to manually serialize and deserialize a type, so how would you use a converter *together with* source generation for automatic serialization?

Comment: I'm using option #3 (adding it to ```JsonSerializerOptions.Converters)```. Custom converter is only for ```MyType```, but json contains array of ```MyType``` objects (so source generation would be used for array deserialization and converter for deserialization of MyType objects). Option #2 together with ```JsonSerializable(typeof(MyType[]))``` should work I think.

Comment: I edited the question to provide more details. Option #2 won't work either. It seems custom converters are not supported together with source generation, which is strange since a custom converter already contains (de)serialization code.

Comment: According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-source-generation?pivots=dotnet-6-0#specify-options-by-using-jsonserializeroptions you can create a JsonSerializerOptions, add your converter and then use jsonSerializer.Serialize(
    myType,
    typeof(MyType),
    new MyTypeContext(myJsonSerializerOptions));

Comment: @JuanZamudio It works. Thank you! Would you care posting it as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-source-generation?pivots=dotnet-6-0#specify-options-by-using-jsonserializeroptions) you can create a JsonSerializerOptions, add your converter and use it in the serialization.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    WriteIndented = false,
};
options.Converters.Add(new MyConverter());

var myJsonSerializerContext = new MyJsonSerializerContext(options);
```

You cant share your JsonSerializerOptions with several SerializerContext, another thing it was not clear to me reading the documentation is that you can have one SerializerContext for n types.

So you can have one SerializerContext for all your types initialize and cache it so you can reuse it to avoid allocating more memory.