# Using source generated System.Text.Json parser together with hand written JsonConverters in .NET 6

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a library which can be used as a standalone API client which is using polling and in a webhook using ASP.NET Core. Currently it uses Newtonsoft.Json library, but I'd like to migrate it to STJ with source generated converters on .NET 6 so it can be used in AOT scenarios.

I struggle to understand how I can have multiple generated `JsonSerializerContext`s and combine them with hand written json converters in such a way that users of my library can augment their own instances of `JsonSerializerOptions` since their applications in ASP.NET Core might have their own conventions and I don't want to impose my settings on all of their code, only on the types provided by my library. I've read that `JsonTypeInfoResolver.Combine` might help, but it was introduced in .NET 8 and currently I can't use .NET 8 since .NET 6 is not EOL and won't be for sometime. Can someone help me understand how this could be achieved?

Comment: Hi @Aleksey Usatov, you could pls check [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70803684/11398810).